# how could i make working self-hosted openid provider, connected to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, openid, phpmyid, xrds

**Aim:**
To have own OpenId provider connected with self-hosted Wordpress blog, so Wordpress admin could use his OpenId to login to Admin Panel, and also to comment other blogs with this OpenId.

Blog address: http://blog.blomqvist.no
OpenId provider: /id/
OpenId created: same as blog address

**WP Plugins used:**

WP-Yadis 1.2.1

XRDS-Simple 1.0

OpenId 3.3.2

I have installed phpMyId as OpenId provider. I have managed to connect created OpenId and management panel login, so Admin could login to management panel with created OpenId.

However, i can't use this OpenId anywhere else, not on blogspot, not on other wordpress blogs etc.

Comment: temporary fixed, with external OpenId from myopenid. still, haven't managed to make it working with phpMyId

Answer (score 0):

There do seem to be some issues with the phpmyid implementation. I installed it on my blog actually, but I could not use it here on stackoverflow last time I tried (admittedly, about a year ago) and had to use my google openid.

Comment: most strange thing, is that when i were writing question here, i've wrote that created OpenId (i didn't have account on stackoverflow before), and it works here. But not on other blogs.

Comment: also, i'm not sure, if reason is in the phpMyId, as i could use that OpenId with /id/index.php (place, where phpMyId installed). But, that variant is not that good, because after i will comment some blog, link will go to 'mysite/id/index.php' instead of 'mysite'

Comment: That can easily be rectified by putting the following meta tags in your blog's home page:
<link rel="openid.server"
  href="http://yourblog.com/id/">
<link rel="openid.delegate"
  href="http://yourblog.com/id/index.php">

Then you can just use "http://yourblog.com" as your openid URL. This also has the benefit of letting you change your openid provider in the future ;-)